# ANSIBLE: how do i take care of timestamp while using archive module?

Tags: ansible, archive

i m using archive module and i wanted to compress file (*.gz). below is my code

```
- name: zip the files
  archive:
   path: "{{ item.path }}"
   format: "gz"
   remove: "yes"
  with_items: "{{ zipfilelist.files }}"
  register: zip_output
```

After executing the above, i see the timestamp is updated for *.gz file.

whereas when i execute a linux command gzip it doesn't change the time stamp

```
> date && ls -lart abc.txt && gzip abc.txt &&date && ls -lart abc.txt*
Thu Mar 19 15:24:23 CDT 2020
-rw-r--r-- 1 ploln1 tuxedo 825 Mar 19 15:22 abc.txt
Thu Mar 19 15:24:23 CDT 2020
-rw-r--r-- 1 ploln1 tuxedo 421 Mar 19 15:22 abc.txt.gz
```

Do we have any similar attribute/parameter for archive module? or may be any other solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use the file module to modify the time on the files.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/file_module.html#file-module